# Weird behavior on when replacing timezone using pytz timezones vs timezone strings

Tags: python, datetime, pytz

I would expect that replacing `tzinfo` using 'US/Central', would give the same result as using the timezone object (`pytz.timezone('US/Central')`), but apparently it's not:

```
In [5]: import arrow
In [6]: d = arrow.get()
In [7]: cst = pytz.timezone('US/Central')

In [8]: d.replace(tzinfo=cst)
Out[8]: <Arrow [2015-07-22T17:40:30.947579-06:00]>

In [9]: d.replace(tzinfo='US/Central')
Out[9]: <Arrow [2015-07-22T17:40:30.947579-05:00]>
```

Note how the output of line 8 has a different UTC offset than the output of line 9.

Which way is the correct way of replacing a timezone using Arrow and pytz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug. I am guessing you are seeing [issue 154](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow/issues/154) -

> .to() is incompatible with pytz.timezone

You may be seeing the same thing for `.replace()` method. The issue is still open.

I would say use the arrow one, seems like currently arrow and pytz are not that compatible.

Comment: The same problem occurs with raw `datetime` objects too. The timezone object can't know the proper offset unless it also knows what date/time it applies to, and `replace` doesn't give it that information.

Comment: Yes, seems like arrow is using `dateutil.tz` internally. Using `dateutil.tz` gives correct values.

Comment: That's interesting, I wonder why there's a discrepancy with `pytz`? Until you pointed out that `dateutil` worked properly I thought it wasn't possible.

Comment: @MarkRansom: `dateutil` does not work properly with timezones: it just hides the bug. `pytz` makes the bug more apparent. It is like Python 2 -> 3 bytes -> Unicode shift: if you see encoding errors; it does not mean that Python 3 is incorrect; it means the code is broken. Last time I've checked [the errors from 2012 were still present in `arrow`](https://gist.github.com/zed/4127162)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I based my comment on the observation that `dst` reported the proper offset when used with `dateutil.tz.tzlocal()` and did not with `pytz.timezone('US/Central')`, depending on which date it was attached to. It appears that `datetime` expects the tzinfo object to be intelligent and adjust itself depending on the date fed into the various functions, while `pytz` appears to be static. I couldn't quite decipher the link you gave, is there a case where `dateutil` also gives the wrong result?

Comment: @MarkRansom: 1. `pytz` allows to get the correct result in most cases (if used correctly (`localize()`, `normalize()` methods) 2. `dateutil` is known to fail 3. `arrow` uses `dateutil` Conclusion: even if `arrow` uses `dateutil` correctly; it still may fail. The gist demonstrates some failures.